# Thread hangs in BigDecimal.compareTo

Tags: java

We have seen this issue numerous times, can someone explain how this is even possible as BigDecimal is immutable?

```
 java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
2014/03/03 17:10:17.517 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(Unknown Source)
2014/03/03 17:10:17.517 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   at java.math.BigDecimal.bigTenToThe(Unknown Source)
2014/03/03 17:10:17.517 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   at java.math.BigDecimal.bigDigitLength(Unknown Source)
2014/03/03 17:10:17.517 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   at java.math.BigDecimal.precision(Unknown Source)
2014/03/03 17:10:17.517 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   at java.math.BigDecimal.compareMagnitude(Unknown Source)
2014/03/03 17:10:17.517 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   at java.math.BigDecimal.compareTo(Unknown Source)
```

How could this happen?

Comment: Maybe it's too big of a number?

Comment: Where it's possible use `BigInteger` it will speed up a lot.

Comment: @jw23 - Looks like it's trying to use BigInteger -- that may be the problem.

Comment: On suspects that you have a BigDecimal number with a ridiculous scale value.

Comment: Does it just hang forever? or is it something like several-second-hang and then it runs again?

Comment: It seems that it could now have been caused by a never ending loop that was comparing decimals, so may not have been a huge number etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BigDecimal.bigTenToThe` method is calling a `BigInteger` constructor.
This is where it hangs. See the comments below in the source code.
It largely depends on what arguments you're calling this with.
Also, see the return statement. Not sure about the connection you
see with mutability. I don't see any here.

```
/**
 * Return 10 to the power n, as a {@code BigInteger}.
 *
 * @param  n the power of ten to be returned (>=0)
 * @return a {@code BigInteger} with the value (10<sup>n</sup>)
 */
private static BigInteger bigTenToThe(int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return BigInteger.ZERO;

    if (n < BIG_TEN_POWERS_TABLE_MAX) {
        BigInteger[] pows = BIG_TEN_POWERS_TABLE;
        if (n < pows.length)
            return pows[n];
        else
            return expandBigIntegerTenPowers(n);
    }
    // BigInteger.pow is slow, so make 10**n by constructing a
    // BigInteger from a character string (still not very fast)
    char tenpow[] = new char[n + 1];
    tenpow[0] = '1';
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        tenpow[i] = '0';                
    return new BigInteger(tenpow);
}
```

Comment: Although it said it is slow, it doesn't seem anything close to be something that slow that will hang the thread.

Comment: @AdrianShum I don't know exactly. See the subject of this question.